# Texture/UV edit complex shapes and tile/repeat

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to build a level in blender. The shape of the mesh is going okay but the texture behaves strangely.

[image]

As you can see the door texture is distorted. I'm missing something but I don't know what. I also have another question in mind, how do I make the texture repeat? I want more than the 2 pannels I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have not unwrapped the face of the mesh, just tab into edit mode, press **'A'**, press **'U'** and select the unwrap option. If your mesh`s texture is still messy in that case, follow any one of the three methods given below. In the end, I have given the steps of repeating your texture.

**1. Cube projection**

[image]

Tab into **edit mode**, select your face [do not select your body`s face, select the face of the object ;)], press **'U'** and select **'cube projection'**

**2. Smart UV project**

[image]

Tab into **edit mode**, select your face, press **'U'** and select the 'Smart UV Project' then a pop-up menu will show up, press the ok button

**3. Lightmap pack>follow active quads**

[image]

**Repeating the texture**

You wanted to repeat the texture so just scale up the UV map of your face/mesh by pressing **'S'** as *@RyanCallowayArt* said. Here`s a GIF to help you understand the process a little better.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly now :)

Comment: your welcome! :)

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what's going on with your door. It's possible those UVs are not laid out properly. You can try selecting the door faces and unwrapping just those.

If you're not concerned with keeping the UVs within a single UDIM tile, you could scale up your UVs to see the pattern repeated like you want.