# UV edit: Planet texture repeats through all rectangles instead of covering all UV Sphere

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm a complete newbie following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6224Wisxwxc). I have a UV Sphere and a texture image 2000x1000px. I have the add-on UV Squares (I read somewhere in Blender 2.8 I could avoid this add-on with some command, I think it was *Follow Active Quads* but not sure).

I apply the texture image with nodes, but when I apply it, at first in doesn't appear over the object, and after "unwrap" it does appear, but it repeats like a pattern through all sphere surface.

What do I need to do to stretch it all over the surface?

If I use different unwrap options (cube, sphere or cylinder projection) the closest one is the sphere projection, but it still leaves some area uncovered and the poles are displaced (see second capture).

Here is a capture of my layout:

[image: Blender layout and UV editing]

UV wrapping with sphere projection:
[image: UV wrapping with sphere projection]

Maybe there's a response to my problem in this [Texture/UV edit complex shapes and tile/repeat](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/242840/texture-uv-edit-complex-shapes-and-tile-repeat) post, but I'm too newbie to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here: [Why does the texture appear like this after adding a planet map texture to a UV Sphere?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68880/why-does-the-texture-appear-like-this-after-adding-a-planet-map-texture-to-a-uv?rq=1)

I don't know if I should delete this question or leave it for easier search & find in future responses.